# webpack dev server: TypeError: The header content contains invalid characters

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, http-proxy

I have a webpack application and I am using webpack dev server in dev mode to run the app. I am also using the proxy to proxy my requests to the live environments.

The application was previously run using node v4.3.2 with no problems, the app ran fine and proxied correctly. I upgraded node today to version 7.0.0 so I could increase support for es6. When running the app now, I receive the following error for all of my requests:

```
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
_http_outgoing.js:360
throw new TypeError('The header content contains invalid characters');
^

TypeError: The header content contains invalid characters
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:360:11)
at /home/jason/dev/frontend-tsm-holiday-results/node_modules/http-      proxy/lib/http-proxy/passes/web-outgoing.js:96:13
at Array.forEach (native)
at Array.writeHeaders (/home/jason/dev/frontend-tsm-holiday-results/node_modules/http-proxy/lib/http-proxy/passes/web-outgoing.js:90:35)
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/jason/dev/frontend-tsm-holiday-results/node_modules/http-proxy/lib/http-proxy/passes/web-incoming.js:157:20)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:473:21)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23)
at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:362:20)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:551:20)
```

I have had a google around and have found some reference to this problem but I am not sure where the error is coming from and why? It seems to be a problem with http_proxy but I am not sure which module it is coming from.

My npm configuration for webpack is:

```
"webpack": "^1.13.2",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
"webpack-fail-plugin": "^1.0.5",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2",
"webpack-merge": "^0.14.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to fix this in dev env is to edit the actual `node_modules/http-proxy/lib/http-proxy/passes/web-outgoing.js` and replace the line

```
res.setHeader(String(key).trim(), header);
```

with something like

```
      try {
        res.setHeader(String(key).trim(), header);
      } catch (err) {
          console.log(key, header);
      }
```

A proper fix would be to either stop sending invalid characters from the server you're proxying, or to upgrade to WebPack 2.x.